# Replace a case formatted word in a text

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, string-formatting

I have a text e.g. `This is a test text hello world`

and I have list of words with case formatting e.g `HeLLO`, `WORLD`, `TEST` (I have such list of 26,000 words with case formatting in table)

I wonder how to replace the words in text with the list of words with case formatting if any word appears in the text.

e.g output of above string after processing will be `This is TEST text HeLLO WORLD`

I know how to check if string contains a word:

```
if CHARINDEX('ME',@mainString) > 0
begin
    --do something
end
```

also I know how to replace a word in string

```
REPLACE(Column1,'hello','HeLLO')
```

I wonder how to apply this if we have list of thousands of words to be replaced in a text?

Answer (score 0):

Wrote following SP after some google search:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE PROC_FormatText
@TXT NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @TXT = 
    CASE WHEN @TXT LIKE CONCAT('% ',Creator,' %')
    THEN
        REPLACE(@TXT, Creator, Creator)
    ELSE
        @TXT
    END
    FROM [CreatorsList];

    SELECT @TXT;
END
```

Comment: Why don't call Replace directly?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (from [Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2093/standardize-text-with-multi-search-and-replace-function-in-sql-server/)) is to select the replacement into a variable:

**Setup**

```
Create Table Replacements
(
    Initial Varchar(100) Not Null,
    Replacement Varchar(100) Not Null
)

Insert into Replacements (Initial, Replacement) Values ('hello', 'HeLLO')
Insert into Replacements (Initial, Replacement) Values ('world', 'WORLD')
Insert into Replacements (Initial, Replacement) Values ('test', 'TEST')
```

**Replacement**

```
DECLARE @Val varchar(250) = 'This is a test text hello world'

SELECT @Val = REPLACE(@Val, Initial, Replacement)
FROM Replacements

SELECT @Val --This is a TEST text HeLLO WORLD
```

**NB:** Sql Replacements may not be case sensitive (depending on your Collation I believe). If that is the case, then TEST, test, TeST, and TEst (etc) are all considered matches against 'test'. So all these would be converted to uppercase TEST